# Using awk in BASH alias or function

Tags: bash, awk

I've a command that works just fine at the command line, but not when I try to put it in an alias or function.

```
$ awk '{print $1}' /tmp/textfile
0
```

That's correct, as '0' is in position 1 of "textfile".

```
$ alias a="awk '{print $1}' /tmp/textfile"
$ a
1 0 136 94
```

That's the entire line in "textfile".  I've tried every variety of quotes, parentheses and backticks that I could imagine might work.  I can get the same problem in a wide variety of formats.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 69):

You need to escape the `$` like so:

```
 alias a="awk '{print \$1}' /tmp/textfile"
```

Otherwise your alias is:

```
 awk '{print }' /tmp/textfile
```

Which prints the whole file...

Comment: The protocol to say thanks in these parts is to mark the answer as the correct one (by clicking the little check mark to the left). =)

Comment: +1 If I were the owner of this question I would gladly mark this one as the answer. It solved a similar problem I was having.

Answer (score 18):

Use a function instead of alias

```
myfunc(){ awk '{print $1}' file; }
```

Comment: This is certainly the more flexible solution, as it allows the argument vector to be referenced. If, for instance, you wanted to use `"${1:-hardcoded_filename}"` to allow an optional filename to be passed with an explicit default, that will work here but not in the alias approach.

Comment: I think this is the best way to use "awk" instead  "alias" because when you need to use a multiple " or ' it start to be complicated to use alias...
For example:
# not working....
`alias gethaweblist='docker exec haproxy01 cat /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg | grep acl | awk '{print $2 " --> " $7}''`
#The good way
`gethaweblist(){ docker exec haproxy01 cat /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg | grep acl | awk '{print $2 " --> " $7}'; }`