# escape dollar sign in bashscript (which uses awk)

Tags: bash, awk

I want to use awk in my bashscript, and this line clearly doesn't work:

```
line="foo bar"
echo $line | awk '{print $1}'
```

How do I escape `$1`, so it doesn't get replaced with the first argument of the script?

Comment: It won't be replaced. It will be the first word in `"$line"`

Comment: The very purpose of those single quotes around the `awk` "program" is to make sure that bash will not attempt to perform any parameter expantion, so your script will work as expected.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu the word is expansion

Comment: @Nirk: You're right ! And I'm embarrassed (I hope I spelled that right) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your script (with single quotes around the awk script) will work as expected:

```
$ cat script-single
#!/bin/bash
line="foo bar"
echo $line | awk '{print $1}'

$ ./script-single test
foo
```

The following, however, *will* break (the script will output an empty line):

```
$ cat script-double
#!/bin/bash
line="foo bar"
echo $line | awk "{print $1}"

$ ./script-double test
​
```

Notice the double quotes around the `awk` program.

Because the double quotes expand the `$1` variable, the awk command will get the script `{print test}`, which prints the contents of the awk variable `test` (which is empty). Here's a script that shows that:

```
$ cat script-var
#!/bin/bash
line="foo bar"
echo $line | awk -v test=baz "{print $1}"

$ ./script-var test
baz
```

Related reading: [Bash Reference Manual - Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) and [Shell Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)

Comment: @cmbuckley how to escape the dollar sign when it's inside as: `'{print "$line, " $1}'`

Answer (score 4):

As currently written, the $1 will not be replaced (since it's within single-quoted string, bash will not parse it)

If you write `awk "{print $1}"`, bash will expand the `$1` within the double-quoted string

Note that the variable expansion rules depend on the outermost level of quoting, so the `$1` in `"awk '{print $1}'"` will be expanded

Comment: how about make an alias: `alias awkprt='awk "{print $1}"'`,  how to make it not be expanded?

Comment: just found out from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244534/using-awk-in-bash-alias-or-function that we only need to escape by a backslash: `alias awkprt="awk '{print \$1}'"`