# Unix 'alias' fails with 'awk' command

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I'm creating an alias in Unix and have found that the following command fails..

```
alias logspace='find /apps/ /opt/ -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{print $5, $9 }''
```

I get the following :

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Any ideas on why the piped awk command fails...

Thanks,
Shaun.

Comment: It's because you have a `'` before {print... that closes your string. You'll need to escape your quotes properly.

Comment: The proper workaround is to declare it as a function instead.  `logspace () { find /apps /opt -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $5, $9 }'; }` or even better use `find`'s built-in `printf` formatting to extract the fields you want.

Comment: An alternative to jumping through the quoting hooks mentioned in the answers is to use a shell function instead of an alias, like shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7244626/15109

Answer (score 48):

To complement's [@Dropout's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245726/45375):

### tl;dr

The problem is the OP's attempt to use `'` *inside* a `'`-enclosed (single-quoted) string.

The **most robust** solution in this case is to **replace each *interior* `'` with `'\''`** (sic):

```
alias logspace='find /apps/ /opt/ -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | 
                awk '\''{print $5, $9 }'\'''
```

- **Bourne-like (POSIX-compatible) shells do not support using `'` chars inside single-quoted (`'...'`-enclosed) strings AT ALL - not even with escaping**.

  - (By contrast, you CAN escape `"` inside a *double*-quoted string as `\"`, and, as in @Droput's answer, you can directly, embed `'` chars. there, but see below for pitfalls.)
- The solution above **effectively builds the string from multiple, single-quoted strings into which literal `'` chars. - escaped *outside* the single-quoted strings as `\'` - are *spliced in***.
  Another way of putting it, as @Etan Reisinger has done in a comment: `'\''` means: "close string", "escape single quote", "start new string".
- When **defining an alias**, you usually want ***single* quotes around its definition** so as to **delay evaluation** of the command until the alias is *invoked*.

---

**Other solutions and their pitfalls**:

The following discusses alternative solutions, based on the following alias:

```
alias foo='echo A '\''*'\'' is born at $(date)'
```

Note how the `*` is effectively enclosed in single quotes - using above technique - so as to prevent pathname expansion when the alias is invoked later.

When invoked, this alias prints *literal* `A * star is born`, followed by the *then*-current date and time, e.g.: `A * is born at Mon Jun 16 11:33:19 EDT 2014`.

---

**Use a feature called [ANSI C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) with shells that support it: `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`**

ANSI C-quoted strings, which are **enclosed in `$'...'`, DO allow escaping embedded `'` chars. as `\'`**:

```
alias foo=$'echo A \'*\' is born at $(date)'
```

**Pitfalls**:

- This feature is not part of POSIX.
- By design, escape sequences such as `\n`, `\t`, ... are interpreted, too (in fact, that's the purpose of the feature).

---

**Use of alternating quoting styles**, as in @Dropout's answer:

**Pitfall**:

**`'...'` and `"..."` have different semantics**, so substituting one for the other can have unintended side-effects:

```
alias foo="echo A '*' is born at $(date)" # DOES NOT WORK AS INTENDED
```

While syntactically correct, this will NOT work as intended, because the use of *double* quotes causes the shell to expand the command substitution `$(date)` *right away*, and thus ***hardwires* the date and time at the time of the alias *definition* into the alias**.

As stated: When **defining an alias**, you usually want ***single* quotes around its definition** so as to **delay evaluation** of the command until the alias is *invoked*.

---

Finally, a **caveat**:

The tricky thing in a Bourne-like shell environment is that **embedding `'` inside a single-quoted string sometimes - falsely - APPEARS to work** (instead of generating a syntax error, as in the question), when it instead does something different:

```
 alias foo='echo a '*' is born at $(date)'  # DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED.
```

This definition is *accepted* (no syntax error), but won't work as expected - the right-hand side of the definition is effectively parsed as *3* strings - `'echo a '`, `*`, and `' is born at $(date)'`, which, due to how the shell parses string (merging adjacent strings, quote removal), results in the following, *single*, literal string: `a * is born at $(date)`. Since the `*` is *unquoted* in the resulting alias definition, it will expand to a list of all file/directory names in the current directory (pathname expansion) when the alias is invoked.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @VivekAgrawal.

Answer (score 4):

You chould use different quotes for surrounding the whole text and for inner strings.

Try changing it to

```
alias logspace="find /apps/ /opt/ -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{print $5, $9 }'"
```

In other words, your outer quotes should be different than the inner ones, so they don't mix.

Comment: Isn't it about the `$`? I had to escape it to work in this example: `alias ip="ifconfig en1 | awk '/inet / { print \$2 }'"`

Comment: I had to escape $ apart from using different quotes

Comment: In some cases when you mix double quotes and single quotes, you get odd results. Example: alias ipconnected="netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head"

Answer (score 2):

**Community wiki update**:

- The **redeeming feature** of this answer is **recognizing that the OP's problem lies in unescaped use of the string delimiters (`'`) *inside* a string**.
- However, **this answer contains *general* string-handling truths, but does NOT apply to (Bourne-like, POSIX-compatible) shell programming *specifically***, and thus does not address the OP's problem *directly* - see the comments.

---

Note: Code snippets are meant to be **pseudo code**, not shell language.

Basic strings: You canNOT use the same quote within the string as the entire string is delimited with:

```
foo='hello, 'world!'';
    ^--start string
            ^-- end string
             ^^^^^^^^--- unknown "garbage" causing syntax error.
```

You have to escape the internal strings:

```
foo='hello, \'world!\'';
            ^--escape
```

This is true of pretty much **EVERY** programming language on the planet. If they don't provide escaping mechanisms, such as `\`, then you have to use alternate means, e.g.

```
quotechar=chr(39); // single quote is ascii #39
foo='hello ,' & quotechar & 'world!' & quotechar;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, (Bourne-like) shell language is _not_ like every other programming language on the planet: you _cannot_ escape `'` chars. inside `'`-enclosed strings, and there must be no spaces around `=`.

Comment: Indeed, as @mklement0 says you cannot escape single quotes inside single quotes like that. The only thing you can do is use double quotes somewhere or use the (very ugly) `'\''` sequence at each "embedded" single quote. (That is "close string", "escape single quote", "start new string".)

Comment: The above code was never intended to be taken as bash. it was pseudo-code to show how you can't use like quotes inside a string without taking special measures.

Comment: @MarcB: The question is tagged `linux` and `shell`, and uses the `alias` feature, so we're clearly talking about Bourne-like, POSIX-compatible shells (`bash` among them). Your original answer (a) recommends escaping, which is specifically NOT an option in the case at hand, and (b) while recognizing that fact, then uses a _different_ language's syntax as a workaround example. All told, from the perspective of the original question, this answer amounts primarily to a _distraction_, and requires getting past the confusion that that creates in order to get to the _general_ truths it contains.

Comment: @MarcB: I've edited the answer again, to hopefully clarify your original intent while avoiding the distraction aspect.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `$` sign not the awk's single quotes and use double quotes for the alias.

Try this :

```
alias logspace="find /apps/ /opt/ -type f -size +100M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{print \$5, \$9 }'"
```

Comment: hope it works, I am not sure `alias` can expand `""`. let us know if works.