# Strange issue resolving bash environmental variable in nested double quotes

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a setup script that needs to be run remotely on an arbitrary machine (can be windows). So I had something along the lines of bash -c "do things that need environmental variables".

I found some strange things happening with nested quotes + enviornmental variables that I don't understand (demonstrated below)

```
# This worked because my environment was polluted.
bash -c "NAME=me echo $NAME"
> me

# I think this was a weird cross platform issue with how I was running.
# I couldn't reproduce it locally.
bash -c "NAME=me echo "Hi $NAME""
> Hi $NAME

# This was my workaround, and I have no clue why this works.
# I get that "Start "" end" does string concatenation in bash,
# but I have no clue why that would make this print 'Hi me' instead
# of 'Hi'.
#
# This works because echo Hi name prints "Hi name". I thought echo only
# took the first argument passed in.
bash -c "NAME=me echo Hi "" $NAME"
> Hi me

# This is the same as the first case. NAME was just empty this time.
bash -c "NAME=me echo Hi $NAME"
> Hi
```

Edit: A bunch of people have pointed out that the variables get expanded in double quotes before bash -c gets run. This makes sense, but I feel like it doesn't explain why case 1 works.

shouldn't `bash -c "NAME=me echo $NAME"` be expanded to `bash -c "NAME=me echo "`, since NAME isn't set before we run this?

Edit 2: A bunch of this stuff worked because my environment was polluted. I've tried to describe what mistakes I made in my assumptions

Comment: You need to escape the quotes, e.g. `bash -c "NAME=me echo \"Hi $NAME\""`

Comment: Quotes don't nest. When you run `bash -c "NAME=me echo "Hi $NAME""`, the shell parses that as two separate double-quoted sections, `"NAME=me echo "` (which is immediately followed by the unquoted section `Hi`, which will be treated as part of the same word), and the empty double-quoted string `""` (which immediately follows the unquoted variable reference `$NAME`). BTW, in all of these cases, `$NAME` is expanded by your interactive shell before it's passed to the `bash -c` command, so defining `NAME=me` in that shell has no effect.

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of ["Unix 'alias' fails with 'awk' command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245661/unix-alias-fails-with-awk-command).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Doesn't this post suggest that double quotes nest? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289574/nested-double-quotes-in-highly-voted-one-liner

Comment: @FrederickZhang running this locally just printed "Hi" for me.

Comment: sry it should be `bash -c 'NAME=me; echo "Hi $NAME"'`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Wouldn't I get an error while running if this was a quoting issue? (something along the lines of 'Hi' isn't a recognized command?)

This would explain why case 2 doesn't work, but why does case 3 work? (does it have something to do with how 'Hi' is treated as part of the same word?)

btw, thanks for the explanation of the expansion there. I was wondering why that was an issue.

Comment: @FrederickZhang I'm a little confused by why this works. My impression was that single quotes in bash were treated as raw strings (and therefore the variables inside would be interpreted literally. (per this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: Variables are expanded in double quotes, but not single quotes! Your first "This makes sense" example is flawed. Type `NAME=Frank` and then that first line again.

Comment: @Henry Exactly. What's put between the single quotes should (usually) be the same as what you want to run in e.g. interactive bash. So single quotes here make it the same as `bash`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `NAME=me; echo "Hi $NAME"`

Comment: @bitinerant That's a very good point. But, why does this work when NAME isn't set?

Comment: `bash -c "NAME=me echo $NAME"` will print nothing

Comment: All your examples aren't reproducible. Can you run them like `NAME='' bash -c` to make sure you don't have a polluted environment from previous tests?

Comment: @Henry In [the example you linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289574/nested-double-quotes-in-highly-voted-one-liner), quotes are able to nest because the quoting levels are separated by a `$( )` level; inside that is a new quoting context, so quotes inside `$( )` can nest inside of quotes outside of it.

Comment: @hek2mgl Ah, thank you. my environment was definitely polluted and the first example does not work.

Comment: @hek2mgl - you asked "why does `bash -c "NAME=me echo $NAME"` work when NAME isn't set?" It 'works' because `$NAME` resolves to an empty string, so it just does `echo` by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three sources of confusion here: quotes don't (generally) nest, `$variable` references are expanded by the shell even if they're in double-quotes, and variable references are resolved before `var=value` assignments are done.

Let me look at the second problem first. Here's an interactive example showing the effect:

```
$ NAME=Gordon
$ bash -c "NAME=me echo $NAME"
Gordon
```

Here, the outer (interactive) shell expanded `$NAME` before passing it to `bash -c`, so the command essentially became `bash -c "NAME=me echo Gordon"`. There are several ways to avoid this: you can escape the `$` to remove its normal effect (but the escape gets removed, so the inner shell will see it and apply it normally), or use single-quotes instead of double (which remove the special effect of *all* characters, except for another single-quote which ends the single-quoted string). So let's try those:

```
$ bash -c "NAME=me echo \$NAME"

$ bash -c 'NAME=me echo $NAME'
```

(You can't really see it, but there's a blank line after the second command as well, because it didn't print anything either.) What happened here is that the inner shell (the one created by `bash -c`) indeed got the command `NAME=me echo $NAME`, but when executing it expands `$NAME` first (giving nothing, because it's not defined in that shell), and then executes `NAME=me echo` which runs the `echo` command with `NAME` set to "me" in its environment. Let's try that interactively:

```
$ NAME=me echo $NAME
Gordon
```

(Remember that I set `NAME=Gordon` in my interactive shell earlier.) To get the intended effect, you'd need to set `NAME` and then as a separate command use it in an `echo` command:

```
$ bash -c "NAME=me; echo \$NAME"
me
$ bash -c 'NAME=me; echo $NAME'
me
```

Ok, with that out of the way let's move on to the original question about quoting. As I said, quotes don't (generally) nest. To understand what's going on, let's analyze some of the example commands. You can get a better idea how the shell interprets things by using `set -x`, which makes the shell print each command's equivalent just before it's executed:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "NAME=me echo "Hi $NAME""
+ bash -c 'NAME=me echo Hi' Gordon
Hi
```

What happened here is that the shell parsed `"NAME=me echo "Hi` as a double-quoted string immediately followed by two unquoted characters; since there's no gap between them, they get merged into a single argument to `bash -c`. It may seem a little weird having only part of an argument quoted, but it's actually entirely normal in shell syntax. It's even normal to have part of a single argument be unquoted, part single-quoted, part double-quoted, and even part in ANSI-C mode (`$'ANSI-c-escaped stuff goes here'`).

With `set -x`, bash will print something *equivalent* to the command being executed. All of these commands are equivalent in shell syntax:

```
bash -c "NAME=me echo "Hi Gordon
bash -c "NAME=me echo Hi" Gordon
bash -c 'NAME=me echo Hi' Gordon
bash -c NAME=me\ echo\ Hi Gordon
bash -c NAME=me' 'echo' 'Hi Gordon
bash -c 'NAME=me'\ "echo Hi" Gordon
```

...and lots more. With `set -x`, bash will print *one* of these equivalents, and it just happens to choose the one with single-quotes around the entire argument.

Just for completeness, what happened to `$NAME""`? It's treated as an unquoted variable reference (which expands to `Gordon`) immediately followed by a zero-length double-quoted string, which doesn't do anything at all.

But... why does that just print "Hi"? Well, `bash -c` treats the next argument as a command to run, and any further arguments as the argument vector (`$0`, `$1`, etc) for that command's environment. Here's an illustration:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "Args: $0 $1 $2"' zeroth first second third
+ bash -c 'echo "Args: $0 $1 $2"' zeroth first second third
Args: zeroth first second
```

("third" doesn't get printed because the command doesn't print `$3`.)

Thus, when you run `bash -c 'NAME=me echo Hi' Gordon`, it executes `NAME=me echo Hi` with `$0` set to "Gordon".

Ok, here's the last example I'll look at:

```
$ bash -c "NAME=me echo Hi "" $NAME"
+ bash -c 'NAME=me echo Hi  Gordon'
Hi Gordon
```

What's happening here is that there's a double-quoted section `"NAME=me echo Hi "` immediately followed by another one, `" $NAME"`, so they get merged into a single long argument (which happens to contain two spaces in a row -- one part of the first quoted section, one part of the second). Essentially, the `""` in the middle ends one double-quotes section and immediately starts another, thus having no overall effect. And again, the shell decided to print a single-quoted equivalent rather than any of the various other possible equivalents.

So how do we actually get this to work right? Here's what I'd actually recommend:

```
$ bash -c 'NAME=me; echo "Hi $NAME"'
+ bash -c 'NAME=me; echo "Hi $NAME"'
Hi me
```

Since the entire command string is in single-quotes, none of these problems occur. The double-quotes are just normal characters being passed as part of the argument (so double-quotes sort of nest inside single-quotes -- and vice versa -- but it's really just 'cause they're ignored), and the `$` doesn't get its special meaning to the outer shell either. Oh, and the `;` makes this two separate commands, so the `NAME=me` part can take effect before the `echo "$NAME"` part uses it.

Another equivalent would be:

```
$ bash -c "NAME=me; echo \"Hi \$NAME\""
+ bash -c 'NAME=me; echo "Hi $NAME"'
Hi me
```

Here the escapes remove the special meanings of the `$` and enclosed double-quotes. Note that the shell prints exactly the same thing as last time for its `set -x` output, indicating that this really is equivalent to the single-quoted version.