# using awk in .bashrc function

Tags: bash, awk

I'm attempting to get the [Internet Archive Save Page](https://gist.github.com/atomotic/721aefe8c72ac095cb6e) function to work in bash. I've added a semicolon, and am escaping the $s as suggested by [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244534/using-awk-in-bash-alias-or-function).

I'm still getting the following error when I try to execute it:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Here's my current version. I've been trying various versions, escaping the quotes, etc. All with the same aforementioned error.

```
function ia-save() { curl -s -I "https://web.archive.org/save/\$1" | grep Content-Location | awk \'{print https://web.archive.org\$2\}\'; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the backslash before the single quotes.  You'll also need to add double quotes around `https://` etc; you need to decide whether you need a `/` in place of the ``\`` in front of the `$2` — I think you probably do.  And it is saner to use multiple lines rather than cramming everything onto one line.  'One-liner' is a pejorative term, not a term of praise (unless you happen to be programming in APL, but Bash scripts aren't APL).

Comment: Check awk examples :https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Print-Examples.html try:  curl -s -I "https://web.archive.org/save/\$1" | grep Content-Location | awk '{print "https://web.archive.org/$2"}';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function ia-save() {
    curl -s -I "https://web.archive.org/save/$1" |
    grep Content-Location |
    awk '{printf( "https://web.archive.org/%s\n",$2)}';
}
```

Removed a backslash in front of $1 that looked misplaced.

Comment: The awk part probably needs to be: `awk '{printf "https://web.archive.org/%s\n", $2}'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In fact, both backlashes seem to be misplaced. I'll correct them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is just a syntax error; you must not escape the single quotes around the awk program.

However, if you are using `grep` and `awk` at the same time, you are likely using one tool too much. Check this example without the use of `grep`:

```
function ia-save() {
    curl -s -I "https://web.archive.org/save/$1" | \
    awk '/Content-Location/{print "https://web.archive.org/"$2}'
}
```